# Hangfire - deploy while site is running doesnt reload the app c# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I gather this might be a general asp.net question as well. I'm running hangfire and we have noticed that when we publish the app to the site that is acting as a container for hangfire, the deploy causes the app to stop running and the app never 'restarts'. I have logging in the global asax application_start and application_end, and our applicationpreload.cs. When we publish the site I see logs for the application_end event but nothing for the start event - this publish occurs while the site is running.

I have followed the steps on the hangfire site https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html and there are a few msdn articles I have followed on the newer IIS settings to keep the app pool always running and the site auto start enabled but my assumption is that these only help when there is either an iis site restart, or app pool recycle/stop/start, or a request comes into the site itself. My scenario is that we are using iis as the container, there are no requests hitting the site and we publish while the app is running...

I was also under the impression that changing files within the iis directory would cause the app pool to recycle but have now realize this is not the case (and that actually makes sense). We are using asp.net mvc 5, iis 10.

Any help here would be appreciated!!!!

PS I can see the down votes already on this - which is actually quite comical taking into consideration this question covers some fundamental asp.net knowledge... and yes I'm just being honest here in terms of not knowing the answer :)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of testing different variants of solutions I have resolved this.

Comment: how did you resolved ?